# Homework Help: Prime Number Identifier C++

Tags: c++, class, primes

My task for this assignment is to take endless input from a user (ctrl-d terminated) and return a response if the number input is a prime number. The twist to this is that instead of just using the % function for all numbers <= the square root of the number input, I must make a list of prime numbers that covers the number input (if the number input is 6, the list must contain 2,3,5, and 7), linearly search through the list, and return true if the number input is in said list. It also must be in a class.

This is my Isprime function.

```
bool isprime::Isprime(int N){
  int i,primenum,max=1;
  int prime[max];
  prime[0]=2;
  for(primenum=3;prime[max-1]<N;primenum++){
    for(i=2;i<primenum;i++){
      if(primenum%i!=0){
        max++;
        prime[max-1]=primenum;
      }
  }
  for(int j=0;j<max;j++){
    if(N==prime[j])
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

When I run the program, the only number that returns the desirable output is 2 (the one I initially put into the list. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your input in advanced.

Edit 1:When the user is inputting numbers, if the Isprime function returns true, a simple cout << N << " is a prime number" is output. That is what I meant by desirable output.

Edit 2:After editing my function due to some careless bugs, ALL input integers are returning true.

Comment: Can you clarify what your expected output is?

Comment: When the user is inputting numbers, if the Isprime function returns true, a simple cout << N << " is a prime number" is output.

Comment: For instance, when a user types "4" and hits enter, nothing is output. But then when they type "3" and hits enter, it says "3 is a prime number".

Comment: And the only time you get the correct output is when the user has entered `2`?  Otherwise the output is incorrect?

Comment: Correct. The only time the cout is displayed is when I type 2. Every time I type 2.

Comment: @JakeHafendorfer the use of the for loop with the array won't work. As in it does not create a list of prime numbers. I would say before you go too much further with this that you do some basic tutorials in c++ arrays (should make it easier for you to spot issues)

Answer (score 1):

At least two bugs in your original code:

In your code, `max=2` and never changed. The first `for` loop tests `prime[1] < N` which is not initialized.  Then `prime[1]` has been assigned many times by some non prime numbers.

for example, in your first loop, i and primenum are

```
i = 2, primenum = 3, prime[1] = 3
i = 3, primenum = 4, prime[1] = 4
i = 4, primenum = 5, prime[1] = 5 
...
```

Now your new code has errors too

int i,primenum,max=1;
   int prime[max];

You defines one `int` array prime with only `one` element. Then you try to access it like it has more. This is wrong.

And the following is not what you want

```
for(int j=0;j<max;j++){
   if(N==prime[j])
       return true;
}
```

because as I said above, prime[i] for `i>0` is not valide.

Comment: I've edited the function, and now all numbers are returning true. What have I done wrong now?

Comment: I've done even more editing after realizing more mistakes, but I'm still getting the same problem - every input is now returning true.

Comment: When I add to max, it doesn't change the size of the array?